# "npm: command not found" error when deploying Python application to Heroku

Tags: python, reactjs, heroku, npm, deployment

I just created a Heroku account and I'm trying to deploy my existing code. When I try to `git push heroku master` I get the following error:

```
 Counting objects: 348, done.
 Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (207/207), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (348/348), 172.64 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 348 (delta 138), reused 279 (delta 116)
 remote: Compressing source files... done.
 remote: Building source:
 remote: 
 remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the 
 ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below 
 will be used.
 remote:            Detected buildpacks: Python,Node.js
 remote:            See 
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect- 
 order
 remote: -----> Python app detected
 remote: -----> Running pre-compile hook
 remote: ----->Pre-compile hook
 remote: -----> Running Webpack
 remote: jquery-webpack-stats.json created
 remote: webpack-stats.json created
 remote: bin/run_webpack: line 15: npm: command not found
 remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 remote: 
 remote:  !     Push failed
 remote: Verifying deploy...
 remote: 
 remote: !  Push rejected to paytientdesktop.
 remote: 
 To https://git.heroku.com/paytientdesktop.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
 error: failed to push some refs to 
 'https://git.heroku.com/paytientdesktop.git'
```

This is my `app.json` file:

```
   {
   "name": "myapp",
   "description": "Myapp Heroku app.",
  "scripts": {
 "postdeploy": "python manage.py migrate"
},
"env": {
  "ALLOWED_HOSTS": {
  "description": "Django ALLOWED_HOSTS setting, e.g.: 
  .appname.herokuapp.com"
  },
  "DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC": {
    "description": "Heroku setting to disable Django collectstatic (it 
  is run by bin/post_compile)",
  "value": "1"
},
"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": {
  "description": "Django settings Python import path",
  "value": "myapp.settings.production"
},
"SECRET_KEY": {
  "description": "Django SECRET_KEY setting",
  "generator": "secret"
  }
 },
 "formation": {
 "web": {
  "quantity": 1,
  "size": "free"
  },
  "worker": {
  "quantity": 1,
  "size": "free"
  }
 },
 "addons": [
  {
    "plan": "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev",
    "options": {
    "version": "9.5"
    },
  "as": "DATABASE"
  },
  {
    "plan": "heroku-redis:hobby-dev",
    "options": {
    "version": "3.2"
    },
    "as": "REDIS"
  },
  {
  "plan": "sendgrid:starter"
  },
  {
    "plan": "papertrail:choklad"
  },
  {
  "plan": "opbeat:free"
  }
],
 "buildpacks": [
  {
    "url": "heroku/nodejs"
  },
  {
    "url": "heroku/python"
   }
 ]
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

### What's going on here?

Heroku builds applications using [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks), each of which is specific to a particular programming language and toolset.

In many cases Heroku can detect which buildpack it should use by looking for certain indicator files in your repository. For example, [the official Python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) will be invoked if your repository contains a `requirements.txt` file or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files in the root of you repository.

The output from your failed deploy above contains the following information:

```
 remote:  !     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the 
 ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below 
 will be used.
 remote:            Detected buildpacks: Python,Node.js
 remote:            See 
 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#buildpack-detect- 
 order
```

Heroku only runs one buildpack by default and it doesn't know whether it should use its Python buildpack or its Node.js buildpack for your app. It's choosing Python.

### How can I fix it?

The good news is that you can use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-multiple-buildpacks) in a single application. You just need to do a bit of manual work to [tell Heroku which buildpacks it should use, and in what order](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app).

Here is an example that should work for you:

1. First, set one of your buildpacks. I like to use whatever feels like the main language here.

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
   ```
2. Next, add your other buildpacks in the right order, which is controlled by the `--index` argument. It looks like your Python build depends on `npm`, so you need the Node.js buildpack to run *before* the Python buildpack.

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```
3. Confirm that your buildpacks are correctly configured by running `heroku buildpacks`. You should see the Node.js buildpack first and the Python buildpack second.
4. Push your code to Heroku again and watch it compile!

### Why didn't my `app.json` work?

Your `app.json` file lists the Node.js and Python buildpacks. Why didn't it work?

I've never used `app.json`, and I've been using Heroku for roughly five or six years. It's certainly not required for running applications on Heroku.

It looks like [`app.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api) is specifically for use with Heroku's Platform API, which would be used to spin up a brand new app (in contrast with deploying code to an app that's already defined).